# How to redirect new WordPress user to previous page after registering

Tags: forms, user-registration

When a user registers for a WordPress site, they are redirected to the login page after completing the registration form. Is there a way to redirect them to the previous page before filling out the registration form?

Please note that I'm not looking for a custom/static page because the user will be coming from various pages and that's the page I want them to return to - not the same page for every case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `registration_redirect` filter you can use:

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_129618_registration_redirect' );
function wpse_129618_registration_redirect( $redirect ) {
    if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) && 0 != strlen( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ) {
        $redirect = esc_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
    }
    return $redirect;
}
```

Alternately, you can edit the PHP that is generating your `<form>` and add a hidden field named `redirect_to`, using the current page's address (ie, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`).

#### References

- [`registration_redirect` on wpseek.com](http://wpseek.com/hook/registration_redirect/) | [in source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-login.php#L670)
- [`esc_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url)